# Multiple toggling buttons and texts with a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#answer").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

this only works for the IDs `"answer"` and `"button"`, the challenge for me its getting multiple pairs of these IDs (`answer1 - button1, answer2 - button2`, and so on) to work with this single function

Comment: use class instead

Comment: Using a `class` would be a better option if you want to use one function to deal with multiple elements like that. I'm assuming you only want the button to display the answer to the question it is next to (grouped in). If so then this example might be of some help to you. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mh86yjr3/) If that is what you are looking for let me know and I can give more detail about how this functions to give better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using an ID property to call that button (`$('#')`) You want to call them by classes.

IDs should be unique and only used in 1 DOM element.

Trying to use ID the script will only pick the 1st element it comes across; and the code will only work for that one button.

With classes you create an Object for all of your elements, with jQuery you just have to call the element by its class, and run the code normally - I note this because in JS you would have to add the index to the element call.

For example:

```
<canvas id="main"></canvas>

<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<div class="elem"></div>
<script>
  var canvas = $('#main'), // return 1 element
      elements = $('.elem'); // return 3 elements
</script>
```

So for anything that involves multiple elements you must call them by class or tag name.

In vanilla JS you would look at something like this:

```
<script>
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');
  console.log(elem[0]);
</script>
```

So, your code would then just need to call those elements by class; and you can set custom classes for different purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btns = $('.btn');
  btns.click(function() {
      btns.toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Just curious to why you haven't added the `.click()` event to your example/snippet? It doesn't really seem to be worth having a snippet for a incomplete example or one with missing source. Also the OP is asking  for *"(answer1 - button1, answer2 - button2, and so on) to work with this single function"* Which this doesn't include the element for the answer(s) or bind the button to anything.

Comment: @NewToJS I actually had noticed that I was missing the `click` function... I've updated my answer to fit it better

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the relevant `HTML` so I can only guess/assume what it might look like in my demo/example.

For multiple elements it is best to use a `class` to group them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answerTog").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.answer').toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.Question {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Question">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Question One" />
  <span class="answer">Question One Answer.</span>
  <button class="answerTog">See Answer</button>
</div>
<div class="Question">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Question Two" />
  <span class="answer">Question Two Answer.</span>
  <button class="answerTog">See Answer</button>
</div>
<div class="Question">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Question Three" />
  <span class="answer">Question Three Answer.</span>
  <button class="answerTog">See Answer</button>
</div>
```

If your button is before the answer then you can simply use

```
$(this).next('.answer').toggle(1000);
```

`$(this)` will target the specific element used to trigger the function call, in this instance the button being clicked.

1. `.prev('.answer')` will target the **previous** element with the `class` name of `answer`
2. `.next('.answer')` will target the **next** element with the `class` name of `answer`

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mh86yjr3/)

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!